# C++'s extern-"C" functionality to languages other than C

Tags: c++, linkage, extern-c

As it is known, declaring `extern "C"` to C++ function makes its name have C linkage, enabling C code to link.

My question is - are there other programming languages we can make C++ function names have linkage to, something like `extern "Lisp"` or `extern "FORTRAN"`?

If not, why? What is the internal structure behind the `"C"`, that makes the limitations?

What are the alternatives?

Comment: No, because almost everything else is compatible with C and its calling conventions.

Comment: There's extern pascal as well...

Comment: "C" is the only such linkage *required by the C++ standard*, but compilers are free to provide more; that's why it's a string constant.  extern "FORTRAN" would make a lot of sense for compilers that have both C++ and FORTRAN front ends.  I wouldn't expect to see extern "Lisp" if only because a Lisp environment tends to be its own monolith.

Comment: language linkage (extern "C++", extern "C", extern "FORTRAN") is not the same thing as calling convention (stdcall, fastcall, etc), which this was marked as a duplicate for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard, 7.5.2 dcl.link, says:

> Linkage between C++ and non-C++ code fragments can be achieved using a
>   linkage-specification:
>
> ```
> linkage-specification:
>     extern string-literal { declaration-seqopt}
>     extern string-literal declaration
> ```
>
> The string-literal indicates the required language linkage. This
>   International Standard specifies the semantics for the string-literals
>   "C" and "C++". Use of a string-literal other than "C" or "C++" is
>   conditionally supported, with implementation-defined semantics. [ Note:
>   Therefore, a linkage-specification with a string literal that is
>   unknown to the implementation requires a diagnostic. —end note ] [
>   Note: It is recommended that the spelling of the string-literal be
>   taken from the document defining that language. For example, Ada (not
>   ADA) and Fortran or FORTRAN, depending on the vintage. —end note ]

So in principle, implementers can choose to support other linkage specifications than C and C++.

In practise however, on all modern platforms, C linkage is the lowest common denominator. As a general rule, these days, binary interop for languages other than C uses C linkage. On the widely used modern platforms, you will not see anything other than C and C++ linkage.

Comment: `extern "Pascal"` exists (although it's a non-standard extension) - it is used to differentiate between the different parameter passing conventions between C and Pascal.

Comment: @PaulR It's not been used for a very long time (none of my compilers support it, I think), and never by me. And I've done a lot of C/Pascal interop. These days all Pascal compilers can do `cdecl` and `stdcall`.

Comment: Rummaging Google shows that `extern "FORTRAN"` also exists. However, I could not find a reference formally settled the issue - anyone have?

Comment: It used to be common on "classic" Mac OS compilers in the 1980s and 1990s, during the transition from Pascal to C/C++ as the main development languages for the Mac. The Mac toolbox and OS used Pascal calling conventions for historical reasons.

Comment: @Reflection Try finding a compiler that will compile anything other than `extern "C"`.

Comment: @PaulR Well, we are going back a little now!

Comment: Well it seems like only yesterday to me... ;-)

Comment: IBM zOS compiler documents extern "FORTRAN", extern "COBOL", and even extern "PLI"

Answer (score 0):

Most contemporary C++ compilers don't support anything other the `extern "C"` and `extern "C++"` required by the ISO C++ standard. Integration with other languages most commonly uses C calling conventions and `extern "C"`.

And even when non-C calling conventions were supported, they often weren't selected by an `extern` string literal, they still used `extern "C"` but in conjunction with some non-standard calling convention declaration: for example, Microsoft C++ for 16-bit platforms (DOS, Windows 3.x, OS/2 1.x) [used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/obsolete-calling-conventions?view=msvc-170) `__pascal` for the Pascal calling convention and `__fortran` for Fortran, instead of something like `extern "Pascal"` or `extern "Fortran"`.

That said, IBM's contemporary C++ compilers for z/OS support [`extern "FORTRAN"`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=pi-declaring-c-fortran-ilc) for calling Fortran, [`extern "COBOL"`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=ilc-declarations-extern-cobol-linkage) for calling COBOL, and [`extern "PLI"`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=dcpi-declaration-c-calling-pli) for calling PL/I.

Similarly, IBM's ILE C++ compiler on IBM i supports a whole list of different `extern` string literals, see PDF page 338 of [IBM i: ILE C/C++ Programmer's Guide](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_ibm_i_75/pdf/sc092712.pdf), like `extern "RPG"`, `extern "C nowiden"` (which is like `extern "C"`, but turns off integer promotion, so a `short` will actually be passed as a 2 bytes instead of 4), `extern "OS"` (which enables IBM's legacy pre-ILE calling convention).

It appears, nowadays, IBM is the only major C++ vendor who supports non-`"C"`/`"C++"` `extern`, and even for them only on their mainframe and midrange platforms; but, historically, there probably were others.